# How to group by relation property b if property a is null

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing `items`, each `item` belongs to an `store`, e.g:

```
id | name | store_id | price 
1  | hat  | 1        | 110
2  | bag  | 1        | 120
3  | coat | 2        | 130
```

A Store can be canonical *or* a duplicate. A canonical Store has `canonical_id` equal to null, and a duplicate Store has `canonical_id` equal to the ID of the canonical Store, e.g:

```
id | name  | canonical_id
1  | NYC   | null
2  | Bronx | 1
```

I need to group items by their Store to get the total stock value of all items at the store, e.g:

```
SELECT store_id, SUM(price) as `stock_value` FROM items GROUP BY store_id
```

This would produce 2 results, Store 1 has a `stock_value` of `230` and Store 2 has a `stock_value` of `130`.

Because Store 2 is a duplicate of Store 1 the items from Store 2 should be included in the total for Store 1. The goal is for this example to provide a single result of 360.

I think the correct implementation would involve some sort of join which retrieves the Store ID from `stores` by using `IFNULL` to get either the `canonical_id` or `id` after selecting based on `id` from the `items` table, but I'm struggling to implement a solution that works.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

---

Edit: my attempt is as follows, it appears to meet my needs, are there any caveats / issues with my approach?

```sql
SELECT SUM(price) as `stock_value`, IFNULL(stores.canonical_id, store_id) as `store`
FROM items
JOIN stores on stores.id = items.store_id
GROUP BY store
```

Comment: 110 + 120 + 130 = 360 - is that the expected stock value for Store 1?

Comment: @danblack yes, that's right, 360 is the expected total. I've updated my question with an example query I have written that returns my expected result, but I'm not 100% sure if I'm doing it the right way or if this will slow when my table grows.

Comment: So see coalesce

Answer (score -1):

I just realize you don't wanted to keep the `stock_values` of the "children" or "related" stores. However the next approach take those into account too:

```
SELECT
   s.*,
   (SELECT
        SUM(i.price)
    FROM
        items AS i
    INNER JOIN
        stores AS s1 ON s1.id = i.store_id
    WHERE
        s1.cannonical_id = s.id
    OR
        s.id = i.store_id) AS "stock_value"
FROM
   stores AS s
```

Online example: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/srfgK97HEzcVwhwkvVAgLc/2)

If you don't want they, you just could filter the previous query using the condition `WHERE s.cannonical_id is NULL` like this:

```
SELECT
    s.*,
    (SELECT
         SUM(i.price)
     FROM
         items AS i
     INNER JOIN
         stores AS s1 ON s1.id = i.store_id
     WHERE
         s1.cannonical_id = s.id
     OR
         s.id = i.store_id) AS "stock_value"
FROM
    stores AS s
WHERE
    s.cannonical_id is NULL
```

But, you should note that the query you posted on the **updated** question will be better in performance than this approach.